# How do I retrieve a specific split from a file in hdfs?

Tags: hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I'm attempting to debug a Hadoop Streaming Job.  I can see that a given mapper is failing when trying to process hdfs://filepath/filename:364+28.  How can I determine what line / lines in the file match up with 364+28?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try getting that particular split and see what's in there. For example, if you are using C#, you could use **System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("map_input_start")** to get the start of the split and then see what is wrong with that particular split.

Or, if you are using Python, you can use **os.environ["map_input_start"]**. I don't know if there is any direct way to achieve this.

HTH